# Some part of form is hidden and how to keep it shown after submitting?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I've got a problem with a form and select function. Part of the form is visible by default, but some part is dynamic according to what has been chosen in the selection. But when I hit the submit button (outside of form, but pinned to it) everything stays like it was (that's on purpose), but that hidden part hides again.

I'd like to keep it visible, but I have no idea how to reach that.
When selection is changed, I call a JS script that sets .display attribute to block or none.
When a submit button is triggered and an error occurs, I'd like to keep those .display attributes.

```
<section class="container grey-text align-left">
    <form class="white" id=product_form action="addProduct.php" method="POST">
        <div>
            <label>SKU</label>
            <input type="text" name='sku' id='sku' value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($sku) ?>">
            <div class="red-text"><?php echo $errors['sku']; ?></div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id='name' value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($name) ?>">
            <div class="red-text"><?php echo $errors['name']; ?></div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Price</label>
            <input type="text" name="price" id='price' value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($price) ?>">
            <div class="red-text"><?php echo $errors['price']; ?></div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Type Switcher</label>
            <select name='productType' id="productType" onchange="showAttributes(this)">
                <option value="">-- Type Switcher --</option>
                <option value="dvd" <?php if (isset($productType) && $productType == 'dvd') echo "selected"; ?>>DVD</option>
                <option value="book" <?php if (isset($productType) && $productType == 'book') echo "selected"; ?>>Book</option>
                <option value="furniture" <?php if (isset($productType) && $productType == 'furniture') echo "selected"; ?>>Furniture</option>
            </select>
            <div class="red-text"><?php echo $errors['productType']; ?></div>
        </div>
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Part to be hidden dynamically
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        <div id="dvd" name='dvd' class='dvd'>
            <label>Size (MB)</label>
            <input type="text" id=size value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($size) ?>">
            <div class="red-text"><?php echo $errors['size']; ?></div>
        </div>
        <div id="book" name='book' class='book'>
            <label>Weight (kg)</label>
            <input type="text" name='weight' id=weight value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($weight) ?>">
            <div class="red-text"><?php echo $errors['weight']; ?></div>
        </div>
        <div id="furniture" name='furniture' class='furniture'>
            <div>
                <label>Width (cm)</label>
                <input type="text" name='width' id=width value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($width) ?>">
                <div class="red-text"><?php echo $errors['width']; ?></div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Length (cm)</label>
                <input type="text" name='length' id=length value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($length) ?>">
                <div class="red-text"><?php echo $errors['length']; ?></div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Height (cm)</label>
                <input type="text" name='height' id=height value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($height) ?>">
                <div class="red-text"><?php echo $errors['height']; ?></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Part to be hidden dynamically
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        </div>
    </form>
</section>


<?php include('templates/footer.php'); ?>
</body>

<script>
    function showAttributes(productType) {
        if (productType.value == "") {
            document.getElementById("dvd").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("book").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("furniture").style.display = "none";
        }
        if (productType.value == "dvd") {
            document.getElementById("dvd").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("book").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("furniture").style.display = "none";
        }
        if (productType.value == "book") {
            document.getElementById("dvd").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("book").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("furniture").style.display = "none";
        }
        if (productType.value == "furniture") {
            document.getElementById("dvd").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("book").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("furniture").style.display = "block";
        }

    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

About the submission, I'd suggest you control if `$_POST` is coming with data.

e.g.

```php
<form class="<?php if( isset($POST) && isset($_POST['productType']){ echo 'all-visible'; } ?>">
```

and the css

```css
.all-visible div {
  display: block !important;
}
```

For the errors I can't see how you are handling it, but it might be for your case
`sizeof($errors)`

and you could add to the same line as:

```php
<form class="<?php if( (isset($POST) && isset($_POST['productType']) || sizeof($errors) ){ echo 'all-visible'; } ?>">
```